# Why won't this Linq compile?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

In this simplified version of my actual problem, I have two tables: `User` and `Metadata`.
Each user can have a varied number of metadata entries associated with them via a FKEY.

This Linq compiles fine:

```
var user = from u in Context.Users
           join m in Context.Metadata
           on u.id equals m.userid
           select new { u.id, m.value }
```

However, if I replace the 'on' clause line to be:

```
on new { u.id } equals new { m.userid }
```

it fails to compile with this error:

```
error CS1941: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.
```

Does anyone know why?

And for bonus points:

I'm ultimately trying to accomplish a query like this:

```
var user = from u in Context.Users
           join m in Context.Metadata
           on new { u.id, "mystring" } equals new { m.userid, m.key }
           select new { u.id, m.value }
```

Note the use of the literal `"mystring"`.
Needless to say, that doesn't work either.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** SLaks's answer worked, but just to be fully clear about what he's talking about, the final `on` clause that works looks like:

```
on new { id = u.id, key = "foo" } equals new { id = mu.userid, key = m.key }
```

Comment: Why do you need to compare anonymous objects not the fields themselves?

Comment: @zrkms: To join on two fields.

Comment: @SLaks: omg, did not know linq cannot that :-S

Comment: @zerk: It can, but only in as one object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The property names in your anonymous types must match.

You can specify the names like this: `new { UserId = u.id, Key = "mystring" }`

Comment: That works, though I didn't understand what you meant at first (: Added the final working syntax in my question.